# Pass props to the main component from child (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two components. The first component is the main component and it has title 'Select'/'Unselect'

```
export default class Contacts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { check: 0 };
  }

  oneItem() {
    this.setState({ check: this.state.check === 0 ? 1 : 0 });
  }

    render() {
      const { check } = this.state;
      const infoUserLists = UserList;
      const dataUserList = infoUserLists.map((infoUserList, index) => <InfoUserList
        key={`infu_${index + 1}`}
        infoUserList={infoUserList}
        selectAll={this.state.check}
      />);
      return (
        <View>
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.oneItem()}>
                  <NormalText label={check === 0 ? 'Select All' : 'Unselect'} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              {dataUserList}
        </View>
      );
  }

}
```

Also I have child component, and when the user clicks on `"onPush"` function - title Select All/Unselect should changes. So user clicks on `"InfoUserList"` component, but the state of this title is changed in main `"Contacts"` component.

```
export default class InfoUserList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { check: 0, label: 'Select All' };
  }

  onPush() {
    this.setState({ check: this.state.check === 0 ? 1 : 0 });
  }

  render (){
    const { infoUserList, selectAll } = this.props;
    const { check } = this.state;
    return (
      <View key={infoUserList.name}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPush()}>
          <Image source={ check === 1 || selectAll === 1 ? iconsLnk.choose : iconsLnk.plus } />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this. https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17 You will need to make a callback function in your parent class and pass it to the child. Then in the child component use this.props.callbackFunction

Answer (score 0):

To inform a parent of a child change, you need to pass an event handler from the parent to the child, then have the child call the event handler method when the event occurs.

1. Define the event handler in the parent.

   onInfoUserListCheckChange() {
     // do something here
   }

Note: You may need to bind the event handler this in the parent constructor to access this.

```
this.onInfoUserListCheckChange = onInfoUserListCheckChange.bind(this);
```

2. Raise the event from the child.

   onPush() {
       //...
       if (this.props.onCheckChange) {
           this.props.onCheckChange( //the checked value);
       }
   }
3. Pass the handler to the child from the parent

   < InfoUserList onCheck={this.onCheckChange} />

Comment: I think I did something wrong, because it is not working :(